# IIS6 Indexing Service indexing asp.net codebehind (.aspx.cs) files

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, full-text-search

I've setup a few catalogs on an Windows Server 2003 IIS6 install, each tracking files within a website. In the Properties -> Generation Dialog for each catalog, 'Index files with unknown extensions' is turned OFF. 'Inherit above settings from Service' in that dialog is also turned off.

However, the index is returning results for .cs files, along with abstracts for those files. I've emptied and restarted the catalogs but the files are still appearing.

My understanding was the Indexing Service would by default only index HTML, ASCII, and Office Documents. What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully your `.cs` files are within a folder that does not contain other files and filetypes that you *do* wish to index.  If this is the case, you can simply add a `Directory` entry into your Indexing Service catalog, point this `Directory` entry to the actual folder that contains your .cs files and set the "Include in Catalog?" to No.

If this is not the case, I'd strongly suggest that you keep the files that are needed to be indexed either in their own folder, or at least outside of the folder that effectively contains your website's source code.

Alternatively, you could pre-compile your ASP.NET website, which would not only remove all of your .cs files (they would be compiled into one or more .DLL's) it would also improve the initial startup time of the website since the first visitor to a site that is not pre-compiled will force the ASP.NET runtime to invoke a pre-compilation step first, slightly slowing down that user's initial access to the website.